# Problem with history.pushState when using AJAX

Tags: javascript, url, url-rewriting, html5-history

I'm quite new to javascript and history API in particular.

I'm making an AJAX GET request to load next or previous page on a website.

```
function ajax_get_update(url)
    {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        cache: true,
        success: function(result){
              sessionStorage.setItem("result", result);
              update_content(result);
            }
    });
    history.pushState(url, url, url)
}
```

AJAX part and changing page content works perfectly fine. As you can see I'm using `history.pushState(url, url, url)` to add next page to history so I could use back button to get back to that page.

`url` looks something like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page=2`

The problem is if I'd go on `page3` from `page2` and then to `page3` again and so on, history then would contain all these transitions, and when I click on the back button I keep altering back and forth between `page2` and `page3` few times before I get to the `page1` eventually. What I want is `page3 -> page2 -> page1` and so on.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: That is how history works :) You could try to move your `history.pushState()` into the success handler and update the history only on certain cases.

I recommend also to update your history only if the ajax request was successful otherwise your application may have an invalid sate.

Comment: @gearsdigital Good call. Any ideas on how to implement this behaviour `page3 -> page2 -> page1` on a back button? Instead of `page3->page2->page3->page2...`

Comment: Do you have any information about the current page? Other than the `url`?

Comment: @gearsdigital not realy... content is unique though

Comment: But parameter is always `?page`?

Comment: @gearsdigital yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but should fit your needs. The idea here is to update the `window.history` only for newly added urls.

On every successful request we're checking if the current url is present in `myState`. If not we can assume a new page and update the history and putting the url to our private cache `myState`.

This will keep your urls in order and prevent duplicated history entries.

Please be aware that this code is using ES2015. You can search the web for polyfills :)

```
// it is probably not a good idea to keep your own history
let myState = [];

function ajax_get_update(url) {
  $.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    cache: true,
    success: function(result) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("result", result);
      update_content(result);
      update_history(url);
    }
  });
}

function update_history(url) {
  // window.history is only updated when the current url is not
  // saved in our private history
  if (!myState.includes(url)) {
    history.pushState(url, url, url);
    myState.push(url);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill

Comment: `(!state.includes(url))` must be `(!myState.includes(url))`, right?

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Thank you so much for your time and patience.